# ¿Cómo hacer para que los "print" se vayan imprimiendo una por una al oprimir enter?

Tags: python

Intento crear un algoritmo que vaya dando respuestas conforme se oprima <kbd>Enter</kbd>, pero al hacerlo los `print` que he creado y que deseo que se ejecuten conforme se oprima <kbd>Enter</kbd>, siempre se ejecutan todos al mismo tiempo.
Quisiera saber qué escribir o qué condición poner para que los `print` se ejecuten uno por uno al ir tecleando <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```py
print("Un tipo le dice a otro: \"¿Cómo estás?\"")
print('Y el otro le contesta: \'¡Pues anda que tú!\'')
```

Comment: Pon un `input('')` entre cada linea.

Comment: Sean dos o mil líneas de código, siempre es mejor mostrarlas _como texto, con formato_...

Comment: Puedes usar `input` en vez de `print`.